# Server over VPN?

Tags: vpn, router, port-forwarding

I don't know that much about VPN, so it could be that this is utterly impossible. Here's hoping, though.

I would like to forward a port from my router to a machine connected to the network via VPN. That way, I could run a simple server on my laptop, and it would continue to work at the same address no matter where I am. The trick is that I don't want people connecting to the server to have to join the VPN. It should be completely transparent to the end-user.

If it's not possible with VPN, is there some other technology that would make this possible? Basically just forwarding a port to a remote machine, one without a static IP.

Comment: What are you publishing? HTTP or something else?

Comment: where is the VPN Server sitting, would help to have more information on your topology.

Comment: Specifically, I want to serve a Minecraft server. I don't know much about setting up a VPN server, but I would be setting it up on a machine in my house, behind a router with a static IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You have to install the vpn on your router and make sure your vpn server always give the same ip to your laptop. 
(This setup is quite easy using Openvpn as server, but you need a router that has VPN capabilities)

Comment: That said it will likely suck. Totally. YOu are better off moving your minecraft server to a virtual machine you rent. And likely cheaper off, too.

Comment: How will that be cheaper? I already own all the equipment I need (assuming my router supports vpn).

Comment: Also, can you possibly give more details on how this VPN-router setup would work? I'm willing to flash my router with DD-WRT, if thats what it takes.

Comment: You need a Openvpn server (your router can act as the server) - this can be accessible everywhere using dynamic dns (dd-wrt supports this) then you must configure it so your laptop always receive the same address (just one more file with a configuration line) - the client's configuration files already have all the info regarding the server, then forward all traffic getting to you router to the minecraft port to your laptop. Then you only need the dynamic dns of your router to be able to access it from everywhere.